# COUNT all values in a column with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

I am joining three tables and need to return two separate counts, one showing the total number of unique users who have purchased an item, and the other showing the total number of unique users who haven't purchased an item. These are cropped for brevity, but here are the relevant tables:

```
user table
+----------+------+------+-----+
| username | colb | colc | etc |
+----------+------+------+-----+
| user1    | *    | *    | *   |
| user2    | *    | *    | *   |
| user3    | *    | *    | *   |
+----------+------+------+-----+
```

```
purchase table
+------------+---------+----------+------+
| purchaseID | storeID | username | cost |
+------------+---------+----------+------+
|          1 |       1 | user1    | *    |
|          2 |       1 | user2    | *    |
|          3 |       5 | user2    | *    |
|          4 |       3 | user1    | *    |
+------------+---------+----------+------+
```

```
store table
+---------+-----------+-----+
| storeID | storeName | etc |
+---------+-----------+-----+
|       1 | store1    | *   |
|       2 | store2    | *   |
|       3 | store3    | *   |
+---------+-----------+-----+
```

I am currently using this query to get the unique users who have purchased an item from a store:

```
SELECT 
    store.storeID storeID, 
    store.storeName storeName, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN purchase.username IS NOT NULL
                        THEN purchase.purchaseID END) AS purchases
    [Query to retrieve total unique users who have not purchased an item]
FROM store 
LEFT JOIN purchase
    ON store.storeID = purchase.storeID
LEFT JOIN user
    ON purchase.username = user.username
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

I have tried a few different ways, none of which have worked. The issue I've identified is when the LEFT JOIN happens it only returns the matching results for usernames, thus the COUNT won't include the other users in the user table. I have not had any luck finding a way to fix this, so I'm hoping someone on here can lend me a hand. The results I'm hoping to see should be something like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| storeID | storeName | purchases | nonPurchases |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | store1    |         2 |            1 |
|       2 | store2    |         0 |            3 |
|       3 | store3    |         1 |            2 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: In your data sample we can see storeID = 5 in the purchase table. This storeID doesn't appear in the store table. Is that feasible scenario?

Comment: Can you tell us what MySQL version you're using? You can check by running `SELECT version();`. Also, can you confirm that the data in `user` and `store` tables are unique? Meaning there are no duplicate data of user nor store? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is actually quite simple.

First you count all user and subtract te count of distinct purchasers

```
SELECT 
    store.storeID storeID, 
    store.storeName storeName, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN purchase.username IS NOT NULL
                        THEN purchase.purchaseID END) AS purchases,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User) - COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN purchase.username IS NOT NULL
                        THEN purchase.purchaseID END) AS NON_purchases
FROM store 
LEFT JOIN purchase
    ON store.storeID = purchase.storeID
LEFT JOIN user
    ON purchase.username = user.username
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Yep, that is quite simple, and it works! I actually tried something like that but got the syntax all wrong (was trying to subtract by 'purchases' as if it was a variable). Been working on this for a while now and got wrapped up in over-complicated solutions. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The CASE statements make no sense. If purchase.username is null then purchase.purchaseID is also null due to the left join.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with a slightly different approach.

Generate a combination of `store` and `user` using `CROSS JOIN`, make it as a subquery then use that to `LEFT JOIN` with `purchase` table. In `SELECT`, change `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` to `SUM(..)`. Something like this:

```
SELECT us.storeID,
       us.storeName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.username IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS purchases,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.username IS NULL
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nonPurchases
FROM (SELECT storeID, storeName, username FROM user u CROSS JOIN store s) us 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT storeid, username FROM purchase) p
    ON us.storeID = p.storeID
    AND us.username=p.username
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Thanks to David pointing out in the comment that my previous suggestion is not exactly counting unique users. So I made a *quick* modification to make sure that it does what OP wanted in the first place. Therefore I did a `SELECT DISTINCT ...`  on `purchase` table then make it as a subquery for the `LEFT JOIN`. The other parts of the original suggestion remains.

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e970cbe81c8e2a065d8b34137d2d8a2)

Comment: (1) The CROSS JOIN makes no sense in this use-case and may cause performance issues with large datasets. (2) You are not counting distinct users. Add a record to the `purchase`  table with a `storeID` & `username` combination that already exists in that table, and see that you get wrong results

Comment: I agree this might have performance issue but like you said, it depends on the data and I'd like to see in what data scenario this would get wrong results so I'll know where to fix. Without proof, this is just an assumption @DavidדודוMarkovitz

Comment: "Add a record to the purchase table with a storeID & username combination that already exists in that table, and see that you get wrong results" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=993f26676d01c12a3452ce1f1dde693f

Comment: Thanks @DavidדודוMarkovitz , I'll take a look and revise my answer accordingly. I didn't fully understand what you meant in your previous comment, it's my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution.
Please note that the aggregation is done **before** the join.

```
with 
purchases as 
(
    select    storeID
             ,count(distinct username) as purchase
    from      purchase
    group by  storeID
),
users as
(
    select    count(*) as total_users
    from      user
)
select storeID
      ,storeName
      ,coalesce(purchase, 0)               as purchase
      ,total_users - coalesce(purchase, 0) as nonPurchases
      
from   store 
       left join   purchases using (storeID)
       cross join  users
```

| storeID | storeName | purchase | nonPurchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | store1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | store2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | store3 | 1 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a8c57462bcc7073861b132ea1000f18&hide=7)

Comment: that is te same as i wrote, if the case statement maes sense or not is part of thequestion